# background-img has no height or width?

Tags: css

I'm using a CSS background-img. The path is correct, but the image has no width or height.

```
 HTML: 
 <button id="view-switcher-current" class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <i class="icon-switcher-network"></i> Network
 </button>
 CSS:
 i.icon-switcher-network  {
   background-image: url('../img/view-network.png');
 }
```

I can see that the path is correct by inspecting the element and following the link, but I can also see that the image has dimensions of 0px by 0px, so it's not actually being loaded.

I've tried a bunch of things, including `background-size: auto` on the image, and setting `overflow: hidden` on the containing `button`, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: "It is loading okay" "it's not actually being loaded" Wait what.

Comment: @Ankit thats why pic is  not showing

Comment: a image with 0X0 has no data in it so how it can be an image

Comment: @BoltClock have edited to clarify that the path is correct but the image is not being loaded, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything inside your tag, and moreover the tag is an **inline element** so try this

```
i.icon-switcher-network  {
  background-image: url('../img/view-network.png');
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: inline-block; /* <------ Add this here */
}
```

Comment: @PavloMykhalov You added `inline-block` after I answered :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have anything inside your `<i></i>` tags.

`<i></i>` tags are inline so their dimensions are dependent upon their content. If you use a block level element such as a div and give it some dimensions then you will see your background image.